# How te replace Flash in IBM Datastage Hierarchical Data

Tags: flash, websphere, datastage

i am working on IBM Datastage with the composant Hierarchical Data , but those days Flash has endeed and the hier Data is not working properly anymore cause if the end of the flash , the solution that we have right now is to use DFD , a light version of datastage online where you can see ur job in browser and then there you can open the hier data without flash . the prob is that solution is temporary we need a better solution , so i am asking is there a better solution to replace the flash , or force it work , is there any solution we can do it to have the flash again and IBM is not going to fix this issue i saw it on their website , Thank you very much for you help

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [note from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6403307?myns=swgimgmt&mynp=OCSSZJPZ&mync=R&cm_sp=swgimgmt-_-OCSSZJPZ-_-R)

This is for the fat client - another option is the DtaaStage FlowDesigner in the newer Version > 11.5 as an alternative